# Aggregate function for count using MongoDB PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

```
[{'_id': '5ebe39e41e1729d90de',
  'modelId': '5ebe3536c289711579',
  'lastAt': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 6, 42, 44, 79000),
  'proId': '5ebe3536c2897115793dccfb',
  'genId': '5ebe355ac2897115793dcd04',
 'count':'ab'},
 {'_id': '5ebe3a0d94fcb800fa474310', 
  'modelId': '5ebe3536c289711579',
  'proId': '5ebe3536c2897115793d', 
  'genId': '5ebe355ac2897115793',
  'lastAt': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 6, 43, 25, 105000),'count':'cd'}]
```

i've `count` in the above collection documents which is in encrypted form, how can i extract the counts for each day for a week and total count for a week and for a month.
Note: need to extract the sum of the counts

Comment: What do you mean by "is in encrypted form" ? How do you want to sum the encrypted value? Or do you want to count the occurrence of each count value?

Comment: 'encrypted form' means we're saving the encrypted value in count e.g 'ab' as 15 but for every new entry it will be different like 'cd' as 20. For a day i.e Jun,3,2020 , the count (e.g 35 for a today) . For encryption we're using hashid .

Comment: You can't do decryption in MongoDB, so you'll have to query everything and do math operations in Python. By the way, why does it have to be encrypted? If you need to process it in the database, it shouldn't be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for briefing, Can you please tell me how to query to get the count for last consecutive days , for month respectively. it is company policy to keep it encrypted .